# Hive "Too many Mappers" when using Dynamic Partition

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am trying to query data into a partitioned table with dynamic partitions.

```
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=10000;
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=1000;


insert overwrite table reporting.ST_YST_FLATTENED partition (dt)
select * from (
select a.ActivityDate
,to_date(c.datecreated) InstallDate
,lower(a.CountryCode) CountryCode
,a.browserguid
,a.installsource
,p.partner
,sum(a.YSTPageViews) YSTPageViews
,Sum(a.YSTClicks) YSTClicks
,sum(a.YSTSearches) YSTSearches
,a.browser
,dt from X) a
DISTRIBUTE BY dt
```

When I execute WITHOUT the "insert overwrite table reporting.ST_YST_FLATTENED partition (dt)" the number of mappers is 32438 and I get no error. When I try and insert into the dynamic partitions I get:

```
Hadoop job information for Stage-7: number of mappers: 32438; number of reducers: 55
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.LimitExceededException: Too many counters: 121 max=120
```

If I reduce the time frame of the sub query, I can reduce the mappers to 200, but I still get the same error. Increasing the default counters used is not an option at this point.

How do I decrease the number of mappers used or otherwise get the dynamic partitions to work?

Comment: Looking at the error which is `Too many counters: 121 max=120`. Please check [too many counters](http://mapredit.blogspot.in/2012/12/hive-query-error-too-many-counters.html).

Comment: @YoungHobbit I saw guide, but as I stated, I'm not able to increase the map reduce settings at this point. It states "These happens when operators are used in queries," so I guess I'm trying to reduce the operators or shift the load. Also, this is only happening when I use dynamic partitions.